# How to access a field of a type defined in an OCaml recursive module?

Tags: recursion, types, module, field, ocaml

I am working on recursive modules in OCaml and I have some trouble accessing type fields.

If I try to do :

```
module A = struct type t = { name : string; } end
module A2 = 
  struct 
    include A 
    let getName (x:t) = x.name 
  end;;
```

Everything is alright. However, I need a more complex type, forcing me to define my type in a recursive module.

```
module rec B:Set.OrderedType = 
  struct 
    type t = {name: string; set : S.t} 
    let compare _ _ = 0 
  end 
and S:Set.S = Set.Make (B);;
```

Everything still works perfectly. However, the following module is incorrect :

```
module B2 = 
  struct 
    include B 
    let get_name (x:t) = x.name 
  end;;
```

The returned error is "Unbound record field name". What is the problem ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `module rec B:Set.OrderedType =`

Your recursive definition says that module `B` has the signature `Set.OrderedType`, which hides the definition of `t` and in this case, its projections. In `Set.OrderedType`, the type `t` is abstract, like this: `type t;;`.

If you want to show the definition of type `t`, it must be part of the signature. The first example works because you did not offer a signature for module `A`, so it was typed by default with a signature that exports everything.

The example below works for me with OCaml 4.02.1.

```
module rec B: 
sig type t = { name:string ; set : S.t } val compare: t -> t -> int end
=
  struct 
    type t = {name: string; set : S.t} 
    let compare _ _ = 0 
  end 
and S:Set.S = Set.Make (B);;
```

The toplevel confirms the definition thus:

```
module rec B :
  sig type t = { name : string; set : S.t; } val compare : t -> t -> int end
and S : Set.S
```

Comment: For the exact same reason, I guess that giving for `S` the signature `Set.S with type elt = B.t` would also be useful if you intend to manipulate non-empty sets.